# My Windows 7 is not giving good graphics ie., my minimising and maximisation of Windows is not done as squashed and released

Tags: windows-7, aero

My minimising and maximising of Windows is not done as squashed and released it is done directly. I used tuneup utilities then it give me some recommendations then I accepted all of them from then it is happening

Comment: Most so-called system optimisers are nothing but snake oil, used by people who do not know how to maintain their systems properly, or by those desperate to run the latest OS/software on ageing hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Hit your Windows key or click the Start menu and type "Adjust Perform". You should see the item "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows" highlighted. Click it or press enter. This should bring up the "Performance Options" dialog. On the Visual Effects tab, make sure it's set to Custom and then check "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing". You can also set any of the other options the way you like.